Requirements for a positive, finitely additive set function taking real values to lead to a finite limit when applied to increasing sequence of sets.
I'm trying to understand the continuity of measures, and I'm wondering what is the answer to the following question.
Let $E$ be a set and $\mathcal E$ be an algebra (not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra) on $E$. If $(A_n)$ is a sequence of non-decreasing sets in $\mathcal E$, i.e., $A_{n-1}\subseteq A_{n}$. Let $\mu: \mathcal E \to \mathbb R$ be a positive set function that is finitely additive, i.e., $\mu \geq 0$ and $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A) + \mu(B)$ for and $A,B\in \mathcal E$ with $A\cap B = \phi$. It is easy to see that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mu(A_n) = L$, where $L$ can be finite or $\infty$ (with slight abuse of notation). Now I'm looking for a condition that will ensure that $L$ is finite. Will imposing $\mu(E) < \infty$ be a sufficient condition to ensure that $L$ is finite? It will be if $\mathcal E$ is a sigma algebra, but what if it is just an algebra? If it is not sufficient, is there an easy example that shows it?

There would need to exist some $A_n$ with $\mu (A_n) <  \infty$ and for all $k > n$ you have $\mu (A_k-A_n)=0$

But $\mu(\bigcup_i A_i)$ may not be defined. For example, if $E=\mathbb N$ and $\mathcal E$ the collection of sets that are finite or whose complement is finite. Now let $A_n = {2, \dots, 2n}$. Then $\bigcup_i A_i$ is not in $\mathcal E$. Here positivity and additivity of $\mu$ will not lead to $\bigcup_i A_i \subset E$ implying $\mu(\bigcup_i A_i) \leq \mu(E)$ because $(\bigcup_i A_i)^c$ is not in $\mathcal E$. As a concrete example of $\mu$, we can consider $\mu(A) = 1$ if $A$ is infinite and $0$ if finite.

I suppose we could use the same argument without introducing $\bigcup_i A_i$? We know $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1} \subseteq E$ for all $n$. So $\mu(A_n)$ is increasing and bounded from above. Therefore, the limit must exist and must be less than or equal to $\mu(E)$?

Imposing $\mu(E) < \infty$ is a sufficient condition to ensure that $L$ is finite. In fact, ${\mu(A_n)}_n$ is incresing and  bounded from above by $\mu(E)$, so we have, for all $n$, $\mu(A_n) \leqslant L \leqslant \mu(E) < \infty$.
